# Amazon ECS host directory access

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have a solution running locally with docker that I'm trying to deploy at AWS, using ECS. Locally, I have an nginx container that I'm supplying conf files to by using volumes in docker-compose.yml:

```
volumes:
    - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
```

In the ./nginx directory I have two (site-specific).conf files that give configs for a couple of sites. It works beautifully. But when I try to use the ECS Task definition UI, the volumes area doesn't seem to allow any way to make a dir on the EC2 host available to a container. In the 'mount points' area, the source dropdown is always empty, and when I type something like '/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d' in the container path field, nothing is saved.

Any ideas how I can access an EC2 dir from a container in ECS? Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a folder /opt/foo on the instance and put your config there.

In the UI create a new volume for the task definition and give it a name and the path `/opt/foo`

Within the container portion of the task definition in the UI `STORAGE AND LOGGING` will have a drop down for Mount points that will now have the name from the previous step. Choose that and set the container path to where nginx inside the container expects it.

Comment: Whoops. Missed the step on the task definition UI page about defining the volume before heading into the container defn. Works! Thx.